# PHP warnings despite error reporting being turned off

Tags: php, wordpress

I just started getting some warnings both on the front and back end (using Wordpress) of a site I'm working on. Error reporting is turned off using `error_reporting(0);` placed at the beginning of wp-config.php file. I tried to put it into the main index.php file as well, to no avail.

The warnings only started to show up today and they don't show up on the live version of the site, which is at least 99% the same code, same database.

Here are the errors (substituted domain name for domain.com):

> Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/virtual/domain.com/:/usr/share/php/) in /var/www/virtual/domain.com/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2104
>
> Warning: file_exists() [function.file-exists]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/virtual/domain.com/:/usr/share/php/) in /var/www/virtual/domain.com/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2095
>
> Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/virtual/domain.com/:/usr/share/php/) in /var/www/virtual/domain.com/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2104

Why do I get these messages ? Shouldn't `error_reporting(0)` turn off all warnings?

Comment: It should. Either the code that disables it doesn't run, or there is other code that overrides the setting again.

Comment: Could you fix the warnings instead? Are you on shared hosting - can open_basedir be turned off?

Comment: NEVER, and I repeart NEVER disable error reporting!

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta - there's certainly an argument for disabling on-screen in live, since it creates additional assistance for attackers. But yes, warnings certainly should not be ignored.

Comment: The code must run, because it's in wp-config. I checked the theme's function.php file, but there's no error_reporting there. 
I'd rather not mess with the server config... do you think it's safe to turn it off ? How is it possible that yesterday there were no warnings ?

Comment: @halfer preventing error messages from being displayed on-screen should be done by settings the display_errors configuration option.

Comment: @halfer of course, better if you redirect the error to a log system. ;)

Comment: @Oswald - indeed; I wouldn't advocate using `error_reporting` for that purpose `:)`

Comment: @halfer What should I set open_basedir to ? Currently it's "/var/www/virtual/domain.com/:/usr/share/php/"

Comment: @ClaudioLudovicoPanetta For development I agree, never turn error reporting off. However for a live environment you may not want clients seeing warnings and errors.

Comment: @MarianoGrandioso: if you are not on a shared server, turn it off. See http://serverfault.com/q/348786. To turn off, use `php_admin_value open_basedir none`.

Comment: Disabling open_basedir solved the problem. Thank you, @halfer.

Comment: No worries, pleased you fixed it! Don't forget to tick your answer, so this question is marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so in the end I solved the problem by directly modifying the php.ini file. This is the line:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

Thanks, @halfer

Answer (score 2):

Some of the commenters don't seem to know how Wordpress sets error reporting. They say stuff like  "should be done" like this, or that. But the fact is in Wordpress all you have to do is go to wp-config.php and change WP_DEBUG from true to false. That will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Still, you will never solve it by changing a setting which will then be overridden by Wordpress. So you can obviously not put that code in wp-config.php.

Comment: I don't particularly insist on changing a setting which will then be overridden by Wordpress. I'm looking for any solution that will stop the annoying errors from being displayed.

Comment: I'm sorry, in my last comment I was talking about the comments people wrote. I wanted to leave this answer here because for 99 % of the people who find this later on, the comments will be plain wrong and in this case too, many of them are plain wrong. We know Wordpress sets it to false if it can, using the functions mentioned here. So that means either there is code in your theme/plugins that changes that, or you have unusual PHP settings on your server. Those are the two things to look for. Deactivate plugins, change them, see if errors are still shown. If so, it's the server.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "off");
```

However, depending on your host you may not have access to dynamically change ini settings like that.

Comment: @MarianoGrandioso Do you have access to the php.ini file? You could edit that manually. Also, are you making sure that you're placing this above where the error is coming from?

Comment: oh wait a sec, I haven't restarted apache yet... let's see if I can access it

Comment: @MarianoGrandioso Any luck?

Comment: Yeah, this problem was solved. See my own answer. Thanks, everyone !

Answer (score 2):

In wordpress, one can [turn on error reporting](http://www.themesrefinery.com/turn-wordpress-error-reporting/) with just the following lines of code:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```